# SSH connection - run program -> howto to keep program running when the ssh-connection is closed

Tags: linux, ssh

**In short:**
What is the most elegant solution to keep a perl/python/R/etc script/program running on a server (connected via ssh) when the remote server connection is closed (shell-window closed)?

**In detail:**
I have written some scripts that will run several days on our server. However, after connecting to the server via SSH over a linux-shell, starting the program and closing the window will also kill the program - OK, thats not new. But, how must the Server be configured to keep the program running after the ssh-connection is closed?
"screen" can be one solution, hmm but for me that to much typing and sometime I forgot to start a screen session and start the program

Thanks for your advice!

Cheers,
Yeti

Comment: i use cron normally, or put it in server startup config, depends on the nature of the program

Comment: for single/occasional long running things like this I start a tmux session and then run it. some time (hours/days) later can come back and review it `tmux attach`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**NOHUP** - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup

```
ssh your_server
nohup nice perl your_script &
exit
```

Answer (score 2):

if you see the man page of ssh you can find an example below the "-n" option.

```
ssh -n <user>@<server> <cmd> &
```

Comment: what if the server has a password? I got this output `[1] 27113` is that right?

Answer (score 1):

In the hope that someone else might find this question and find this information useful, there is an application called "[screen](http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen)" out there that can also let you achieve this.

Most distributions should have them in their repositories under the `screen` package name. If I wanted to make a screen, I would simply run `screen -dmS screenName command` and it would run the command in a different "screen", which can be accessed with `screen -r screenName`. You can detach from a screen at any time using CTRL+A+D.

I hope someone can benefit from this information, as it is useful when you'd like to run a process but also be able to review its output assuming it has any (which many of my applications do).